# xamarin.android: Giving toast a background color removes the corner radius

Tags: xamarin.android

```
        Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(Application.Context,
                            message, ToastLength.Short);

        toast.View.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#98A5AD"));

        toast.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center, 0, 0);
        toast.Show();
```

This is my custom toast. It takes in blue as a color. This however overwrites the cornerradius. How do I do prevent that from happening?

Also, how can I use a custom font in the toast?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "this is test!", ToastLength.Long);
        toast.View.Background.SetColorFilter(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#98A5AD"), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
       
        toast.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center, 0, 0);
        toast.Show();
```

[image]

If you want to use custom font for toast text, please take a look:

```
Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "this is test!", ToastLength.Long);
        View view = toast.View;
        toast.View.Background.SetColorFilter(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#98A5AD"), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
        TextView text = (TextView)view.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Message);         
        var typeface = Typeface.Create("customfont", Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Bold);
        text.Typeface= typeface;
        toast.Show();
```

About using custom font in Android, you can take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/fonts